# .Net Maui Mobile App w SQLite - Android Emulator - Error System.TypeIntializationException

Tags: sqlite, android-emulator, android-sqlite, maui

I'm attempting to add local SQLite CRUD functionality to a .Net Maui Mobile App.  I've been testing using the Android Emulator.  The app complies but when I navigate to the page with local storage I receive the following error/exception:

System.TypeIntializationException

Looking at the call stack it appears the SQLite Assemblies are are Not loading. I tried installing both sqlite-net-pcl v1.6 & v1.8, but neither correct the issue.  I've included a screenshot but happy to supply the complete Call Stack if requested.

[image]

Model:

```
 namespace AutoPopulatePage.Models;
 
 public class OfflineNote
 {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int OfflineNoteId { get; set; }
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
 }
```

DB Service:

```
namespace AutoPopulatePage.Services;

public class LocalDb
{
    private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

    public LocalDb(string dbPath)
    {
        _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        _database.CreateTableAsync<OfflineNote>();
    }

    public Task<List<OfflineNote>> GetOfflineNotesAsync()
    {
        return _database.Table<OfflineNote>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveOfflineNoteAsync(OfflineNote offlineNote)
    {
        return _database.InsertAsync(offlineNote);
    }
}
```

Code Behind Page:

```
private static LocalDb localDb;

public LocalDbPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs 
args)
{
    cvOfflineNotes.ItemsSource = await 
    LocalDbPage.LocalDb.GetOfflineNotesAsync();
    base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
}
public static LocalDb LocalDb
{
    get
    {
        if (localDb == null)
        {
            localDb = new LocalDb(Path.Combine 
            (Environment.GetFolderPath
            (Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
             , "OfflineNote.db3"));
        }
        return localDb;
    }
}
```

Full Call Stack

```
> am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.companyname.autopopulatepage/crc642644e5feaf3758af.MainActivity"
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.companyname.autopopulatepage/crc642644e5feaf3758af.MainActivity }
[utopopulatepag] Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
[utopopulatepag] Unquickening 12 vdex files!
[utopopulatepag] Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
[utopopulatepag] The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[NetworkSecurityConfig] No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
[debug-app-helper] Checking if libmonodroid was unpacked to /data/app/~~5jkHyz22Y2n7NBtD6CScwg==/com.companyname.autopopulatepage-UwkmFr7ZbsEMegXfGJoJNw==/lib/x86_64/libmonodroid.so
[debug-app-helper] Native libs extracted to /data/app/~~5jkHyz22Y2n7NBtD6CScwg==/com.companyname.autopopulatepage-UwkmFr7ZbsEMegXfGJoJNw==/lib/x86_64, assuming application/android:extractNativeLibs == true
[debug-app-helper] Setting up for DSO lookup in app data directories
[debug-app-helper] Added filesystem DSO lookup location: /data/app/~~5jkHyz22Y2n7NBtD6CScwg==/com.companyname.autopopulatepage-UwkmFr7ZbsEMegXfGJoJNw==/lib/x86_64
[debug-app-helper] Using runtime path: /data/app/~~5jkHyz22Y2n7NBtD6CScwg==/com.companyname.autopopulatepage-UwkmFr7ZbsEMegXfGJoJNw==/lib/x86_64
[debug-app-helper] checking directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/lib`
[debug-app-helper] directory does not exist: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/lib`
[debug-app-helper] Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/user/0/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[debug-app-helper] Checking whether Mono runtime exists at: /data/app/~~5jkHyz22Y2n7NBtD6CScwg==/com.companyname.autopopulatepage-UwkmFr7ZbsEMegXfGJoJNw==/lib/x86_64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[debug-app-helper] Mono runtime found at: /data/app/~~5jkHyz22Y2n7NBtD6CScwg==/com.companyname.autopopulatepage-UwkmFr7ZbsEMegXfGJoJNw==/lib/x86_64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[utopopulatepag] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[DOTNET] JNI_OnLoad: JNI_OnLoad in pal_jni.c
[monodroid] Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__`
[utopopulatepag] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=10.0.2.2:62532,embedding=1
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly AutoPopulatePage.dll
[monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46080
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Mono.Android.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Java.Interop.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Collections.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/AutoPopulatePage.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Java.Interop.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Collections.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives(System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32)' to /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:124 [0x00000].
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Threading.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Threading.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Threading.Thread.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Threading.Thread.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll [External]
[utopopulatepag] Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
Loaded assembly: data-0x786e810c5020 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x786e81105060 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x786c6cc9a040 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x786e810f5050 [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly netstandard.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/netstandard.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Linq.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Linq.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointSendToIde(System.String)' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:419 [0x00000].
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Json.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Text.Json.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ComponentModel.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.ComponentModel.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ObjectModel.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.ObjectModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.Uri.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Private.Uri.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Loader.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Loader.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointCheckpoint()' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:414 [0x00000].
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Memory.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Memory.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Net.Primitives.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Net.Primitives.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Net.Http.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.Xml.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Private.Xml.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll [External]
[utopopulatepag] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 506(75KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 1807KB/2409KB, paused 325us total 4.033ms
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView.dll [External]
[libEGL] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
[libEGL] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
[libEGL] loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Thread started:  #3
Thread started:  #4
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll [External]
[utopopulatepag] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
[utopopulatepag] Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager2.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager2.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll [External]
[TabLayout] MODE_SCROLLABLE + GRAVITY_FILL is not supported, GRAVITY_START will be used instead
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager.dll [External]
Thread started: .NET Timers #5
[HostConnection] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x786d110cc090, tid 1828
[HostConnection] HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
[OpenGLRenderer] Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
[EGL_emulation] eglCreateContext: 0x786d010df450: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
[EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0x786d010df450: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x786ca1766400) (first time)
[Gralloc4] mapper 4.x is not supported
[HostConnection] createUnique: call
[HostConnection] HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x786d110c83d0, tid 1828
[goldfish-address-space] allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
[goldfish-address-space] allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f7ffe000 size 0x2000
[HostConnection] HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
[utopopulatepag] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 1780(187KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3227KB/6454KB, paused 357us total 8.464ms
[Choreographer] Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
Thread started: .NET ThreadPool Gate #7
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly Xamarin.AndroidX.Emoji2.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/Xamarin.AndroidX.Emoji2.dll [External]
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #11
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly SQLite-net.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/SQLite-net.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Threading.Tasks.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Threading.Tasks.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly mscorlib.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/mscorlib.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.autopopulatepage/files/.__override__/SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] Shared library 'e_sqlite3' not loaded, p/invoke 'sqlite3_libversion_number' may fail
**System.TypeInitializationException:** 'The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.'

[monodroid-assembly] Shared library 'e_sqlite3' not loaded, p/invoke 'sqlite3_libversion_number' may fail
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue `[monodroid-assembly] Shared library 'sqlite3' not loaded, p/invoke 'sqlite3_libversion_number' may fail` running Maui app on Android emulator. iOS version works.

Comment: https://github.com/ToddTaylorPL/AutoPopulatePage

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: **[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl.dll**.  To reproduce the issue start the app and on the startup page click button "Local DB Page". @JessieZhang

Comment: Yes, it is the case as you said.   Based on complexity of this issue, we need to do more research. We will keep you informed if there’s any update. 
If you have further information, please post and it will be helpful for us to understand.

Comment: I get the same error. `System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.'`, did you ever find a solution ?